# Python: how to delete duplicates in Nx3 numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates

I have Nx3 numpy array, let say:

```
a=[[1,1,1],[1,2,3],...,[2,1,3],[2,2,2]]
```

In my case, I don't care about the position of the elements in my "sub 3D array" and I consider them as duplicates:

[1,2,3] == [2,1,3] == [3,1,2] = ...

I would like to delete these duplicates and so get:

```
a_new = [[1,1,1],[1,2,3],...,[2,2,2]]
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to do this job.

Any help are welcome and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort` and `unique`:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,1,1],[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,2,2]])
np.unique(np.sort(a, axis=1), axis=0)

array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```